# how to get the primary key in a DataGridView in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataGridView which shows a table from a database.

Is it possible to get the name of the table's primary key from the DataGridView object?

Is there a way or should I use SQL for this?

Comment: Usually the UI elements have no idea of the backend (or at least they shouldn't).

Comment: From c# you can use GetSchema which can get a lot of object from the database.  Not sure if you can get the primary keys.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-schema-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.. actually the solution was simple and it is based on what @Robert said.

DataGridView cannot know the structure of the table that it shows. Therefore I needed to find it using SQL on the table that the DataGridView data is originated from